# disable view rendering in magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, zend-pdf

How to call the following two lines in magento's `\app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\Helper\Data.php` file

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();   
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
```

Actually there is a self created function getPdf() in Data.php which is used to generate pdf of wishlist items. It generates PDF with no error by using the statement

```
$pdf->save("hello.pdf");
```

But When I use  the following statement

```
$pdfString = $pdf->render();
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfile.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/x-pdf");
echo $pdfString;
```

It throws error: Adobe reader couldn't open myfile.pdf because it's not either a supported file type or because the file has been damaged. Now I need to call these two lines

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();   
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
```

in getPdf() function so that, it will not add html contents in pdf documents. Can you help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you echo `$pdfString`, add the following code to disable view rendering and the layout:

```
$vr = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
$vr->setNoRender(true);

$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$layout->disableLayout();
```

If the `Mage::getSingleton()` call doesn't return the correct layout object, you can also try `$layout = $this->getLayout();`

Comment: I tried the above of chunk of code before echo  $pdfString, the Pdf document still contains html contents. Now the actual pdf contents gets disappeared which means that the above code removes Pdf contents instead of html contents. Also I think that Mage::getSingleton('core/layout'); or $layout = $this->getLayout(); doesn't returns correct layout. Can you please help...

Comment: For better understanding my problem can you please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214990/zend-pdf-document-throws-error-in-magento-due-to-presence-of-html-contents/12217962#12217962

Comment: Can you try calling `$this->getLayout()` instead and see if that works?  $pdfString shouldn't disappear since you are echoing it directly.  Disabling view rendering and layouts doesn't affect content that is `print`ed or `echo`ed.