# zend_pdf document issue in windows 7

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento-1.7, zend-pdf

I am using zend_pdf to generate pdf in magento 1.7 and  I have tried something like

```
public function getpdf()
 {
 $pdf = new Zend_Pdf(); 
 $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
 $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
 $page->setFont($font, 24) ->drawText('Hello World', 72, 720);
 $pdf->pages[] = $page;
 $pdfString = $pdf->render();
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=helloworld.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/x-pdf");
echo $pdfString;
 }
```

Now the problem is when Pdf is generated on Windows 7, it doesn't open and throws error message saying "Adobe reader couldn't open helloworld.pdf because it's not either a supported file type or because the file has been damaged". I noticed this error occurs due to presence of html contents in pdf document. I am sending you pdf document as link https://dl.dropbox.com/u/45895040/helloworld.pdf.

If pdf is generated in Mac OS X, it opens sucessfully there

For better understanding just try to follow the steps as mentioned in [Zend_pdf document throws error in magento due to presence of html contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214990/zend-pdf-document-throws-error-in-magento-due-to-presence-of-html-contents/12217962#comment16382418_12217962).

Can anyone guide me how to set headers properly so that generated pdf can be opened on any browser irrespective of any Operating System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line of code right before the echo statement:

```
        ob_end_clean();
```

That should do the trick.