# Zend-pdf: Pdf does not begin with %PDF-1.4

Tags: php, zend-framework, header, http-headers, zend-pdf

I have tried as following in magento 1.7

```
 $pdf = new Zend_Pdf(); 
  ....
  ....
 $pdfString = $pdf->render();
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=helloworld.pdf");
 header("Content-type: application/x-pdf");
 echo $pdfString;
```

Now the issue is that when PDF is generated it throws error message: Pdf does not begin with
%PDF-1.4. Also I noticed that it contains html contents. Can anyone please tell me what should I do in order to  avoid html contents from being appended with Pdf's own contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [zend_pdf document issue in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279768/zend-pdf-document-issue-in-windows-7)

Stick `ob_end_clean()` before the `echo` statement.